# How to give storage permission in flutter desktop windows?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

**I don't know how to give storage permission in flutter desktop windows.so please guide me if any one know.**

Comment: You should clarify the context for your question, since the standard Flutter Windows build is a Win32 application, and has no permission system. Is this a question about Windows Store? Alpha UWP builds? Something else?

Comment: i understand win32 no need any permission to write in storage